# Generalized Back Propagation Algorithm for Neural Networks?

Tags: python, math, neural-network, gradient-descent

I'm making a neural network program from scratch, and I'm trying to make a Generalized Gradient Descent and Back Propagation Algorithm with Python and numpy. Right now it looks like this:

```
def back_prop(y, layers, lr=10e-8):
    for i in range(len(weights) - 1, -1, -1):
        cost = -1.0*(y - layers[i+1])
        for j in range(len(weights[i])):
            for k in range(len(weights[i][0])):
                weights[i][j][k] -= lr*2*cost[j]*layers[i][k]
                
        for j in range(len(biases[i])):
            biases[i][j] -= lr*2*cost[j]
        y = la.inv(weights[i].T @ weights[i]) @ weights[i].T @ (y - biases[i])
    return 0
```

Here, y represents the label y or actual y, and layers represents the layers of the neural network after forward propagation. This code seems to work for a 1-layer neural network with no activation function (or a linear activation function). A 1-layer neural network is simply just one Weight Matrix and One bias vector. If I try to make more layers and if I include activation functions it doesn't work.
The line I wrote:
`y = la.inv(weights[i].T @ weights[i]) @ weights[i].T @ (y - biases[i])`
is based off some math I wrote on a whiteboard, but now it seems to be wrong. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this algorithm or how to make it work alongside Activation Functions besides just linear activation function. Anyone have any advice?

Edit:
including some scratch work
[Gradient of F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsH14.jpg)
[Previous Layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Suq.jpg)

Comment: can you include the math you wrote on the whiteboard?

Comment: Oh yeah, I'll try to include a photo

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote my math and figured out my issue. From this I have rewrote the code so that it works now. Here's the new code:

```
def back_prop(y, layers, lr=10e-8):
    cost = -1.0 * (y - layers[len(weights)])
    for i in range(len(weights) - 1, -1, -1):
        newcost = 1.0 * weights[i].T @ cost
        for j in range(len(weights[i])):
            for k in range(len(weights[i][j])):
                weights[i][j][k] -= lr*2*cost[j]*layers[i][k]
                
        for j in range(len(biases[i])):
            biases[i][j] -= lr*2*cost[j]
        cost = newcost
    return 0
```